# Integration of roots and trig functions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm trying to take the indefinite integral of

$$\sqrt{1 + 4x^2}$$

I know that the integral of $ \frac{ 1 }{\sqrt{1+4x^2} }$ is $\frac{arcsinh(2x)}{2}$ So I did:

$$\frac{1+4x^2}{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}dx$$

Set $u =1+4x^2$ and set $dv = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$

If you integrate by parts, you'll get the "uv" term and then I integrated the "udv" term again by parts to get something kinda long (you can work it out if you want to) that may or may not simplify into something convenient, but I'm wondering what the best way to integrate this would be.

Comment: The standard thing to do here is to remember that $1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$, and substitute accordingly ie. $2x=\tan(u)$.

Comment: (if you work it out, you can post an answer to your own question!)

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt is correct, but if you know hyperbolic functions you could also substitute $2x=\sinh(u)$ since $1+\sinh^2(x)=\cosh^2(x)$. That would be easier in this particular case.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Good point